# what does this loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can someone help me to understand what this loop is doing? I am very new in Node JS and I just want to filter display a csv data with grafana, influxdb and Node js. (Without the nom Modules)

```
let orders = [] 

for (let line of lines) {
    let columns = line.split(";");
    let orderID = columns[1]
    let type = columns[2]

    if (!orders[orderID]) {
        orders[orderID] = {
            id: orderID
            events: []
        };
    }

    orders[orderID].events.push(type);
}
```

I don't understand especially the if loop. What does it?

Comment: It looks like it's initializing a new object to represent an order, if none exists for the given id

Comment: The `if` isn't a loop, but a condition. This is a very common syntax you can find in almost every programming language. It instructs the interpreter to perform the operation(s) within the block only IF the condition(s) within the parentheses evaluates to true. In your case, this condition is preparing an order object within your `orders` array to house events on the order. This is important, because without this preparation your next line would cause an error in your code as the order object for `orderID` would be undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The for loop is taking an array of lines. Columns are being split by ';' terminators.

```
line //=========> contains text   'text A ; text B'

let columns = line.split(";");
```

The columns are being split by ';' terminator, so the columns variable will contain array with partitions.

```
console.log(columns) //=======> ['text A','text B']
```

Next the `orderID` variable will simply store whatever id is received similarly the type as well

```
let orderID = columns[1]
let type = columns[2]
```

Next, the if conditon checks if the order array doesnot contain any element with the `OrderId` index. If simply means it checks if an order exists or not.

If it doesn't, the condition is deem true and orders array is inserted with an object of `OrderId` and empty array of event.

```
if (!orders[orderID]) {
   orders[orderID] = {
   id: orderID
   events: []
   };
}
```

The last line simply pushs type key received from object in current events array.

```
orders[orderID].events.push(type);


let orders = [] 


for (let line of lines) {
    let columns = line.split(";");
    let orderID = columns[1]
    let type = columns[2]


if (!orders[orderID]) {
   orders[orderID] = {
   id: orderID
   events: []
   };
}

orders[orderID].events.push(type);
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks :) it helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You have an array of lines (strings).

You iterate this array with `for..of` it's almost equal to simple `for`, but instead of indexes you work with items directly.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
  const line = lines[i];
  console.log(line);
}
/* ~ equal to */
for (line of lines) {
  console.log(line);
}
```

You split every `line` item by `;`.
It means that you split string `line` into array of tokens by separator `;`.

```js
const array = "A;B;C".split(';'); // ["A", "B", "C"]
```

Then you take second and third elements of tokens array and assign them to variables `orderId` and `type`.

```js
const orderID = array[1]; // "B" (second)
const type = array[2]; // "C" (third)
```

Then you check if element with index `orderID` exists in the `orders` array.
If not, you create it.

```js
let orders = [] 
/* ... */
if (!orders[orderID]) {
        orders[orderID] = {
            id: orderID,
            events: []
        }
    }
```

Then you push in `events` array value of the `type` variable.

```js
orders[orderID].events.push(type);
```

I hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thanks it helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Let start from resolve `CSV` shortcut: `C`omma `S`eparated `V`alues but many `CSV` files use a semicolon instead of a comma.

```
for (let line of lines) { // iterate line by line from CSV file
    let columns = line.split(";"); // split line by known separator (;)
    // You must know what value is in which column
    let orderID = columns[1] // get value from first column and bind it to 'orderID' variable
    let type = columns[2] // get value from second column and bind it to 'type' variable 

    // check did order on given position exists 
    if (!orders[orderID]) {

    // if not create empty one
        orders[orderID] = {
            id: orderID
            events: []
        };
    }

    // add `type` to order `events` 
    orders[orderID].events.push(type);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> // Some dummy csv and lines

```
const csv = `
test;0;usa
test;1;spain
test;1;japan
test;2;china
test;3;korea
test;3;singapore
`.trim();
const lines = csv.split("\n");


let orders = [];

for (let line of lines) { // iterate line by lines
  let [_, orderID, type] = line.split(";"); // split line by known separator (;), 2nd colum as orderID, 3rd as type
  if (!orders[orderID]) { // check did order on given position exists or not, if not create empty one
    orders[orderID] = {
      id: orderID,
      events: []
    };
  }
  // add/pus `type` to order `events` 
  orders[orderID].events.push(type);
}
console.log(orders);



// Output
/*
[ { id: '0', events: [ 'usa' ] },
  { id: '1', events: [ 'spain', 'japan' ] },
  { id: '2', events: [ 'china' ] },
  { id: '3', events: [ 'korea', 'singapore' ] } ]
*/
```

> // Same using reduce

```
const orders2 = lines.reduce((all, item) => {
  let [_, orderID, type] = item.split(";");
  if (!all[orderID]) {
    all[orderID] = {
      id: orderID,
      events: []
    };
  }
  all[orderID].events.push(type);
  return all;
}, []);
console.log(orders2);
```

> **Running:**

```js
// Some dummy csv and lines

const csv = `
test;0;usa
test;1;spain
test;1;japan
test;2;china
test;3;korea
test;3;singapore
`.trim();
const lines = csv.split("\n");


let orders = [];

for (let line of lines) { // iterate line by lines
  let [_, orderID, type] = line.split(";"); // split line by known separator (;), 2nd colum as orderID, 3rd as type
  if (!orders[orderID]) { // check did order on given position exists or not, if not create empty one
    orders[orderID] = {
      id: orderID,
      events: []
    };
  }
  // add/pus `type` to order `events` 
  orders[orderID].events.push(type);
}
console.log(orders);



// Output
/*
[ { id: '0', events: [ 'usa' ] },
  { id: '1', events: [ 'spain', 'japan' ] },
  { id: '2', events: [ 'china' ] },
  { id: '3', events: [ 'korea', 'singapore' ] } ]
*/

// Same using reduce

const orders2 = lines.reduce((all, item) => {
  let [_, orderID, type] = item.split(";");
  if (!all[orderID]) {
all[orderID] = {
  id: orderID,
  events: []
};
  }
  all[orderID].events.push(type);
  return all;
}, []);
console.log(orders2);
```

Comment: Thank you! it helped to a much